# Problem wrapping a binded function that makes an XMLHttpRequest in a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, reference, xmlhttprequest, bind

Here I'm attempting to reuse a function (load_content) that does an XMLHttpRequest,

```
function load_content(location){

  var number = this.getAttribute("trat_number"); 
  var content = tratamientos.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  var title = content.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];

  var template = new XMLHttpRequest();
  template.open('GET', 'mods/data_tratamientos.php', true);
  template.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(template.readyState == 4) {
       if(template.status == 200) {
                    //Here it does some other things
       }
       else
       {
          alert( " An error has occurred: " + template.statusText); 
       }
     }
 };
 template.send();
}
```

inside this other function(which happens to do another XMLHttpRequest), and then perform some other operations when it's done.

```
   function get_template(location){

     //Here I get a few things to work with
     var template = new XMLHttpRequest();
     template.open('GET', location, true);
     template.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(template.readyState == 4) {
         if(template.status == 200) {

             //More actions take place here...

             var trat_n = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
             for (i = 0, j = 1 ; i < trat_list.length; i=i+2, j++){
               trat_n[i].setAttribute("trat_number", 'trat_'+j);
               trat_n[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

                  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                  var load = load_content.bind(this);
                  var test = Promise.resolve(load());
                  load().then(function(){

                    //THIS IS WHAT I'M AIMING FOR

                  });
               });
              }
          }
       else
       {
          alert( " An error has occurred: " + template.statusText); 
       }
    }
  };
 template.send();
}
```

Apparently, I already managed to execute load_content when the LIs are clicked, but I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at HTMLLIElement. (readmore.js:81)

Of course this is my first time dealing with Promises, as you can see. The thing is: I don't want load_content to return a Promise, because I would have to rebuild a lot more code. I just simply want to wrap it in a Promise for this one time, if possible.

Comment: you don't return anything in `load_content` ... you need to return a Promise for `.then` to work ... but you don't even create a Promise in that function

Comment: It is not possible to wait for `load_content` without returning promise because `template.onreadystatechange` is an asynchronous function. Why don't you want to return promise btw? It's pretty simple, just adding 2 or 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaromanda X mentioned, you have to return a `Promise` for `.then()` to work.

Here's the example:

```
function load_content(location) {
    // you have to return a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var number = this.getAttribute("trat_number");
        var content = tratamientos.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
        var title = content.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];

        var template = new XMLHttpRequest();
        template.open('GET', 'mods/data_tratamientos.php', true);
        template.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (template.readyState == 4) {
                if (template.status == 200) {
                    //Here it does some other things

                    resolve(template.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    alert(" An error has occurred: " + template.statusText);
                    reject(template.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        template.send();
    });
}
```

```
function get_template(location) {

    //Here I get a few things to work with
    var template = new XMLHttpRequest();
    template.open('GET', location, true);
    template.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (template.readyState == 4) {
            if (template.status == 200) {

                //More actions take place here...

                var trat_n = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
                for (i = 0, j = 1; i < trat_list.length; i = i + 2, j++) {
                    trat_n[i].setAttribute("trat_number", 'trat_' + j);
                    trat_n[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

                        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                        var load = load_content.bind(this);
                        // var test = Promise.resolve(load());
                        load().then(function (response) {
                            // Here you can deal with the response
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                alert(" An error has occurred: " + template.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    template.send();
}
```

Comment: @RamaFeichu Yes it remains exactly the same functionality only now it can be cascaded with `.then()` or using `await` in an `async` function.